# Output html code into a div using php if browser width is

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi there i have an offcanvas menu which i want to output to a div using get_template_part WP function.

I previously was using CSS which worked fine using bootstrap visible / hidden classes, but I was doubling up on output code for desktop and mobile view.

here is my code

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 1270) {
           jQuery("body div").find(".mobileMenu").html('<?php get_template_part("templates/menu-offcanvas-right-mobile"); ?>');
        }
    });
 </script>
 <div class="mobileMenu"></div>
```

I see the code inside the html(`<div ...`) but I am getting errors e.g `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Not sure if this is the best way to do this any help would be great.
Cheers

Comment: `PHP` is a server-side language so it will run on the server before any browser rendering. Are you trying to render a different view for mobile users because if so you can style the website so that you can render the content once but use CSS media queries to control the layout depending on device/resolution/height-width. I know this comment isn't explaining the reason for your current error but if the reasons above are correct then I would recommend you look into [**MDN web docs- media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Yes I was previously using CSS media queries which worked fine however my code was doubling up desktop view and mobile view although one or the other was hidden (display:none). W3C detected double up of ID's etc

Comment: Id's should never be duplicated. If you want to identify elements but multiple of them as a group then use a class name - `class="something`" attribute. Also `php` isn't required for detecting device or rendering a layout so you might not have to bother with using `php` unless your content is being delivered server-side but even then you can cut down on the source if you can get the media queries working. If you can explain more of what `get_template_part("templates/menu-offcanvas-right-mobile");` returns then I might be able to further advise you or if you explain your expectations.....

Comment: If not then my advice might be of no use to you. I'm just going from what you have shared and wondering if I can save you from having a big task into something simple.

Comment: I agree with @NewToJS, but let me add to it... if you are getting a syntax error due to an invalid or unexpected token in the `.html('<div>...')` part, then you most likely have at least one `'` somewhere in the HTML that is returned by your PHP function. This causes part of that HTML to be interpreted as part of your JavaScript (or jQuery) and thus reporting an error. So I still believe that this is not the best approach and I wouldn’t recommend it at all, but this could be helpful. I hope.